# Dual boot 19.10 not possible alongside Win 10 "RST Premium with Optane"?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Acer Predator Triton 500 **2x512GB SSD in RAID 0**

I've followed all the suggested methods. I can change the BIOS SATA from RST Premium to AHCI to run the 19.10 Ubuntu installer, but it never sees the partitions or Windows, it just sees two blank hard drives.

I can't boot into Windows with AHCI (have to switch back to RST Premium). I did set it to safeboot. I deleted secure boot settings in the BIOS and turned of Windows fast boot.

I see Intel says

> "Dual OS Boot systems--systems with more than one storage drive, each
>   containing an OS--aren't supported and results can't be guaranteed."

Is it just not possible for Ubuntu to see the Windows partition with "RST Premium with Optane" and RAID-0?

---

Update: Have installed Ubuntu within Windows in VirtualBox instead of dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

i have a acer nitro 5 2020 and i have dual booted windows 10 and ubuntu 19.10 with intel RST premium with optane . so there is no problem with that i think you need to focus on SSD side of things because that could be the main issue. two different hard drives are also not an issue because i have dual booted on different hard drives in the past. So , your problem is SSD discoverability on linux.

Comment: Thanks yes I don't think 1 v 2 drives makes any difference. Ubuntu can't see the partitions in either one. It just sees two blank drives.

Comment: yeah bro i wish i had any experience with SSD's. i woud be more help ful. hope your problem get fixed soon.